# In Vue.js how to make a nav fade in on scroll down event and fade out where scroll pageYOffset = 0

Tags: vue.js, animation, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I am working on a Vue.js project and i am stuck on a small animation for the header navbar.

I want to listen to the users scroll event and fade in and out the nav-bar, if user scrolls down, fade in and if user scrolls back to top: 0 fade out, and show a full screen intro without navigation bar. the nav is fixed/sticky at the top.

How can i do this using Vue.js?

for a better visualization :
[this is the screenshot of my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMwA6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adapted [this solution](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky) to your case by adding `showNavbar` property to your data object that change the navbar state and using `transition` element with `name='fade'` that wraps `navbar` element, in your CSS you have to add the following rules :

```
.fade-enter-active
{
transition: all 1s;
  }
 .fade-leave-active {
 transition: all 2s;
  }
 .fade-enter, .fade-leave-to  {
   opacity: 0;
  }
```

finally you should add an event listener to scrolling event like :

```
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
```

and checking the value of `window.pageYOffset` as follow :

```
  window.pageYOffset>0?this.showNavbar=true:this.showNavbar=false;
```

the following code works fine :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    showNavbar:false
    }
    },
  methods:{
   handleScroll (event) {
      window.pageYOffset>0?this.showNavbar=true:this.showNavbar=false;
    }
  },
    created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed () {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
.fade-enter-active
 {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 2s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to  {
  opacity: 0;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>
<transition name="fade">
<div id="navbar" class="sticky" v-if="showNavbar">
  <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
</div>
</transition >

<div class="content">
  <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```